# How to get an MPMediaItem from a saved playbackStoreID (i.e. for Apple Music playlist items)

Tags: ios, mpmediaitem, mpmediaquery

I'm making a music player app that can access and play music and playlists that come from Apple Music and the iOS music library, and I want to be able to save and reload the user's song queue across app launches. If a song is locally stored on a phone, it's easy enough to save its MPMediaItem.persistentID and then load the item back up using a predicate like this:

```
let predicate = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: savedLocalID, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID);
let songQuery = MPMediaQuery.init(filterPredicates: [predicate]);
```

However, with songs that come from playlists saved from Apple music, their MPMediaItem.persistentID isn't preserved across app launches and doesn't work to load them as MPMediaItems. I was hoping that MPMediaItem.playbackStoreID could be used in a similar way with MPMediaQuery, but when I try to make a predicate using it with MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackStoreID I get the error "MPMediaPropertyPredicate cannot filter using the playbackStoreID property." Any ideas how to get an MPMediaItem from a saved MPMediaItem.playbackStoreID, or another property I'm missing that works for non-local Apple Music files? Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/AppleMusicWebServicesReference/index.html

Comment: All I can find in Apple's documentation is how to use that playbackStoreID to get info about an item using an https request, not how to get a playable MPMediaItem.

Comment: Right, so similar to the complaint made here: http://www.openradar.me/28569390

Comment: Hmm, so sounds like at least as of iOS 9.3 you can set a playlist that uses all playbackStoreIDs (which local files don't have) but you can't necessarily get MPMediaItems from playbackStoreIDs. I can't believe how idiotic Apple is with this set of APIs.

Comment: I mean, i can believe it by this point...

Comment: Well, I don't know that it's idiotic, because after all the song might be remote. You can't just hand an MPMediaItem to a player if the item isn't there to begin with. That's why we now have APIs like [MPMusicPlayerStoreQueueDescriptor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayerstorequeuedescriptor). You use this to set the queue of the `applicationQueuePlayer`. Perhaps that's what you're looking for?

Comment: Might help to watch https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/502/

Comment: Well I can get these as MPMediaItems when the user selects a playlist that contains them, even though they're remote, and can play them like I can local files. I think it really is dumb on Apple's part :]. I'll take a look at that video, thanks!

Comment: Also, that MPMusicPlayerStoreQueueDescriptor looks like it only works if all the items have storeIDs, which lots of local files may not.

Comment: @Thomas I'm having the same problem, used to be able to look these up via persistentId, but somehow not anymore. How do you find the MPMediaItem for apple music songs nowadays?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found is to scan the library on app startup and keep a lookup table of playbackStoreIDs vs persistentIDs. I use Core Data for this.
I found that going through all library items is fast. Updating the table can take long-ish the first time because it has to save all the pairings, but as my entity is indexed by persistentID, further updates are fast.
Times will vary depending on device and library size, but this is a possible approach.